# How to create a Python COM server without admin permissions?

Tags: python, com

I'd like to run a Python COM server and be able to ping it from another Python client without having to provide admin access. (I've already followed the tutorial [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartServerCom.html) and gotten the COM communication to work with admin rights).

I don't know what I'm missing, but nothing seems to happen when I run this COM server code. I also get a handle printout of `65536`, which I'm guessing is meaningless. (I'm aware that the HKCU registry can be edited without admin permissions, though I don't really understand how I should go about making that happen with this server code.)

server.py

```
import pythoncom
import win32com
from win32com.server.util import wrap

_reg_clsid_ = "{6B39CAA1-A320-4CB0-8DB4-352AA81E460E}"

class ActiveObject:
    _public_methods_ = ["ping"]

    def ping(self):
        return "1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ob = win32com.server.util.wrap(ActiveObject)
    handle = pythoncom.RegisterActiveObject(ob, _reg_clsid_, 0)
    print(handle)
```

client.py

```
import win32com.client
server = win32com.client.Dispatch("{6B39CAA1-A320-4CB0-8DB4-352AA81E460E}")
print(server.ping())
```

Let me know if you need more information from me. (I'm using Python 3.8 on a Windows 10 machine)

As an aside, I'm also fine with using AutoHotkey to help register the server in the registry if that helps. (My ultimate goal is to have an AutoHotkey client talk to the server, but first I just need to get this server to work with a basic python client without having to give admin permissions)